# Correct way to set html div position when inserting html via ajax

Tags: html, css, position

I am dynamically building html in javascript.  This will then be inserted into an element.  What is the correct way to set the top, left, width and height properties within the html that I am creating.  My current technique works in IE, but not Chrome or Safari.  This is how I'm currently doing it (controlgroup is an object containing my properties):

```
html += '<div id="' + controlgroup.id + '" class="controlgroup ui-widget-content"';
html += ' style="{';
html += 'top:' + controlgroup.top + '; left:' + controlgroup.left + ';';
html += 'width:' + controlgroup.width + '; height:' + controlgroup.height + ';';
html += '}">';
html += 'cg:' + controlgroup.id + ' ' + controlgroup.left + ',' + controlgroup.top;
html += '</div>';
```

I then do this:

```
$('#formcontainer').html(html);
```

I need the ability to specify exact coordinates, so I can't use 'predefined' css classes here.  Thanks very much.

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, why not use it to position the elements? http://jsfiddle.net/acqQe/

Comment: I could do that but I was hoping to keep the build process to a single nested loop, rather than building all the elements in loop 1 then positioning in loop 2. Just wondered if there was an accepted 'better way'

Comment: You don't need the brackets in your style tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You'll want to make that you are using `left`, `right`, `height`, and `width` values that have `px` attached. So instead of setting `width:50;` set it to `width:50px;`.

2) You'll want to add `position:relative;` to your style.

3) The `{}` brackets are not needed

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/6fbvT/2/

Comment: could I use position:absolute?  That would still position the div within its parent container right?  Thanks.